# Unable to loop inside media Folder in Umbraco 8

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco8

I have 2 images in a media folder and I need to display them. I've been trying to loop inside the folder but have not been unable to.

That's my code:

```
  var media = Model.Value<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("mediaFolder");

    foreach (var item in media){
    <img src="@item.Url"/>
    }
```

The result is a compilation error:

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what `Model` is?  What's the header of your view look like?  How is the Model populated?

Comment: Is media folder a multiple item content picker?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the property "mediaFolder" is a media picker that points to the folder, the code would need to be:

```
 var media = Model.Value<IPublishedContent>("mediaFolder");

 foreach (var item in media.Children()){
    <img src="@item.Url"/>
 }
```

The example code that you have above would only work if the "mediaFolder" was a multiple content picker that had picked the two files individually.